# Mongoose populate not working. How to resolve?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to do mongoose populate but it not working below is given my schema. How can I solve this issue? Why is it not working I working many solution on stackoverflow but all are not working even I read out doc that also not worked for me. Now someone can please help me How can I sort it?

Auth

```
const authSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String
    },
});

const auth = mongoose.model('auth', authSchema);
```

Project

```
const teamSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    auth_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'auth'
    }
});

const projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    team: {
        type: [ teamSchema ]
    }
});

const project = mongoose.model('project', projectSchema);
```

Query:

```
project.find({}).populate(team.$.auth_id).exec((err, result) => {
    if(err) rej(err);
    res(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation you should do something like:

`project.find({}).populate('team').exec.....` or  `project.find({}).populate('auth_id').exec.....`

If you want to filter an specific auth_id the criteria should be in the find not in the populate, populate apparently receives key name to be populated

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

For me, the verison of mongoose 6.* don't work populate.
I stay hour to descover.

try downgrade your mongoose to versions 5.*

commands:
yarn remove mongoose
yarn add mongoose@5.13.14

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a virtual.
something like:

```
userSchema.virtual('car', {
  ref: 'Car',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'owner',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use aggregate with `$lookup` like below:

```
project.aggregate([{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: '',
        localField: '',
        foreignField: '',
        as: ''
    }
}])
```